# scheduling a task twice a day with Laravel

Tags: laravel, cron

I'm trying to schedule a command twice a day:

Here is my code:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {

        $morningCarbonHour = Carbon::now();
        $morningCarbonHour->hour = 23;
        $morningCarbonHour->minute = 27;
        $morningCarbonHour->second = 00;

        $hourIni = $morningCarbonHour->format('H:i');

        $nightCarbonHour = Carbon::now();
        $nightCarbonHour->hour = 23;
        $nightCarbonHour->minute = 28;
        $nightCarbonHour->second = 00;

        $hourFin = $nightCarbonHour->format('H:i');

        $schedule->command('check:time')
                 ->twiceDaily($hourIni,$hourFin)
                 ->timezone('America/Mexico_City');
    }
```

I get this error message:

```
[2016-05-31 23:29:01] production.ERROR: exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Invalid CRON field value 23:27,23:28 at position 1' in /home/forge/myproject/vendor/mtdowling/cron-expression/src/Cron/CronExpression.php:147
```

Stack trace:

I don't really know why??? Any Idea???

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`twiceDaily` accepts parameters as hours.
Default values is `public function twiceDaily($first = 1, $second = 13)` which means task will be execute daily at 1:00 & 13:00.

You are trying to run task 23:27 and 23:28 which is technically not available using this (`twiceDaily`) method, because it does not accepts minutes as parameter.

---

**Solution**

Change `twiceDaily()` to `<command>->cron('27,28 23 * * *');`.
It will run Your command at 23:27 and 23:28.

---

Or if You want to run command two times a day, with a different hour and minutes, You should use two separated commands with `dailyAt()` (two `dailyAt()` on one command, will override and will not work as You want).

Comment: Ok, I understand. In the real case, the algorithm to get the 2 hours (init and end) is a bit tricky, so, I couldn't do it like you say. Should it work with 2 ->dailyAt('13:00'); or the second one will it override the first one? Basically, the 2 hours are going to be random hours like : 09:xx and 19:xx

Comment: 23:27 and 23:28 is just for testing

Comment: Two `dailyAt()` will override themselves. If You have to stick to `dailyAt()`, the only solution would be to put 2 same commands, but with different execution dates.

Comment: oooo. so, 2 dailyAt in 1 command will override, but I should make 2 commands, and it should be ok?

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro Thank You, I added part about `dailyAt()`.